# How can an Outlook add-in check if an appointment has a Teams meeting?

Tags: outlook, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I'm developing a meeting provider add-in for Outlook. One issue my customers have is Outlook automatically enabling a Teams meeting when composing appointments, which users are not aware of. It's reportedly common for users to send an event with two sets of meeting details attached (Teams and my add-in).

When a user opens my add-in I would like to notify them that they already have a Teams meeting enabled. How can an Outlook add-in check if an appointment has a Teams meeting?

Comment: (1) Currently, for which platform you are testing this: Outlook Win32, Outlook Mac or OWA. (2) Currently, there is no Office JS API which can provide this information about "Teams Meeting" enabled. (3) What is the user-flow you are envisioning after you notify user about "Teams Meeting enbaled" - are you also expecting a way to disable "Teams Meeting" for all future events via an Office JS API?

Comment: (1) Win, Mac and OWA. Mobile's online meeting provider interface avoids the issue. 
(2) 
(3) My add-in both allows the user to pick for a list of meeting rooms and 1-click add a meeting room. Picking from a list in the task pane, we would show a small notice indicating that a Teams meeting is also enabled for the appointment. 
For the 1-click meeting room, create a similar notice with Office.NotificationMessages API. This is to help the user realise they will have two meeting rooms enabled.

Comment: I don't think Office.js should be able to disable "Teams Meeting". Users/Admins should make that choice through other means. It would be nice to have though. I think this is somewhat achievable via https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/set-organizationconfig?view=exchange-ps

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no Office JS API which can provide this information about "Teams Meeting" enabled.

Currently the feature, you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [Tech Community Page](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions). Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when we go through our planning process.